How best to redistribute predicted daily sales to the hourly level?
I have hourly sales data (0600H - 2200H). I have aggregated them to daily and made predictions based on the daily level. This is because I found that predicting at daily level leads to predictions with higher accuracy.
I also have another data frame with hourly (0600-2200H) proportion of sales.
I have tried the plain method of mapping the daily to hourly based on the proportion, but it was not very accurate (the total daily sales does not tally).
I want to redistribute the daily predicted level based on the historic proportion of sales by the hour using the hierarchicalforecast library. Or how best can I redistribute the predicted daily to hourly level?
average_hourly_proportion df:
date hour proportion
0 2023-01-01 6 0.000000
1 2023-01-01 7 0.000000
2 2023-01-01 8 0.016458
3 2023-01-01 9 0.017825
4 2023-01-01 10 0.0390

daily df:
date sales
0 2023-01-01 3840.10
1 2023-01-02 3323.80
2 2023-01-03 2605.40
3 2023-01-04 2616.60
4 2023-01-05 2622.89
5 2023-01-06 3596.50
6 2023-01-07 3769.77
7 2023-01-08 3572.30
8 2023-01-09 2381.50
9 2023-01-10 2900.00

hourly_x:
date hour sales proportion
0 2023-01-01 6 0.00 0.000000
1 2023-01-01 7 0.00 0.000000
2 2023-01-01 8 63.20 0.016458
3 2023-01-01 9 68.45 0.017825
4 2023-01-01 10 150.05 0.039075

combined_hourly:
date    hour    sales   promo_available
0   2023-01-01  6   0.00    1
1   2023-01-01  7   0.00    1
2   2023-01-01  8   63.20   1
3   2023-01-01  9   68.45   1
4   2023-01-01  10  150.05  1
... ... ... ... ...
7220    2024-02-29  18  373.00  1
7221    2024-02-29  19  445.00  1
7222    2024-02-29  20  431.80  1
7223    2024-02-29  21  458.20  1
7224    2024-02-29  22  373.80  1
7225 rows × 4 columns
Code:
from hierarchicalforecast.core import HierarchicalReconciliation
from hierarchicalforecast.methods import BottomUp, TopDown, MiddleOut
from statsforecast.core import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import AutoARIMA, Naive
# retain rows where date column is from 2023-01-01 to 2024-02-29
combined = combined[(combined['date'] >= '2023-01-01') & (combined['date'] <= '2024-02-29')]
# retain only columns 'date', 'hour' 'promo_available' and 'sales'
combined = combined[['date', 'hour', 'promo_available', 'sales']]
combined_hourly = combined.groupby(['date', 'hour']).agg({'sales': 'sum', 'promo_available': 'max'}).reset_index()

# Define the levels
days = combined_hourly['date'].dt.date.unique()
hours = combined_hourly['hour'].unique()

# Create the summing matrix S
num_days = len(days)
num_hours = len(hours)

# Bottom-level (hourly) series
bottom_series = combined_hourly.groupby(['date', 'hour']).size().reset_index(name='count')
num_bottom_series = bottom_series.shape[0]

# Higher-level (daily) series
daily_series = combined_hourly.groupby(['date']).size().reset_index(name='count')
num_daily_series = daily_series.shape[0]

# Initialize the summing matrix with zeros
S = np.zeros((num_daily_series, num_bottom_series))

# Fill the summing matrix
for i, day in enumerate(days):
    daily_indices = bottom_series[bottom_series['date'] == pd.to_datetime(day)].index
    S[i, daily_indices] = 1

S_df = pd.DataFrame(S)

# Create tags dictionary
tags = {
    'levels': ['Daily', 'Hourly'],
    'labels': {
        'Daily': [str(day) for day in days],
        'Hourly': [f"{day} {hour}" for day in days for hour in hours]
    }
}

# # Output the summing matrix and tags dictionary
# print("Summing Matrix S:")
# print(S_df)

# print("\nTags Dictionary:")
# print(tags)

combined_hourly_copying = combined_hourly.copy()

# Create hourly series
combined_hourly_copying['unique_id'] = combined_hourly_copying['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_H' + combined_hourly_copying['hour'].astype(str)
combined_hourly_copying['ds'] = combined_hourly_copying['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(combined_hourly_copying['hour'], unit='h')
combined_hourly_copying_hourly = combined_hourly_copying[['unique_id', 'ds', 'sales']].rename(columns={'sales': 'y'})

# Aggregate to create daily series
combined_hourly_copying_daily = combined_hourly_copying.groupby('date').agg({'sales': 'sum'}).reset_index()
combined_hourly_copying_daily['unique_id'] = combined_hourly_copying_daily['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_D'
combined_hourly_copying_daily['ds'] = combined_hourly_copying_daily['date']
combined_hourly_copying_daily = combined_hourly_copying_daily[['unique_id', 'ds', 'sales']].rename(columns={'sales': 'y'})

# Combine hourly and daily series
Y_df = pd.concat([combined_hourly_copying_hourly, combined_hourly_copying_daily], ignore_index=True)

# Output the Y_df DataFrame
print(Y_df)

Y_df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(Y_df['ds'])

# Calculate the split point (80% of the data)
split_index = int(len(Y_df) * 0.8)

# Ensure the split respects the chronological order
train_df = Y_df.iloc[:split_index]
test_df = Y_df.iloc[split_index:]

h = len(test_df)  # Forecast horizon (number of periods to forecast)

# Define the models you want to use
models = [
    AutoARIMA(season_length=119),  # Adjust season_length according to your data's seasonality
    Naive()
]

# Create the StatsForecast object
fcst = StatsForecast(
    df=train_df, 
    models=models, 
    freq='H',  # Set frequency to hourly ('H') since your data is hourly
    n_jobs=-1
)

# Fit the models and generate forecasts
forecasts = fcst.forecast(h=h)

# Example reconcilers
reconcilers = [
    # BottomUp(),
    TopDown(method='forecast_proportions'),
    # MiddleOut(middle_level='Country/Purpose/State', top_down_method='forecast_proportions')
]

# Initialize HierarchicalReconciliation
hrec = HierarchicalReconciliation(reconcilers=reconcilers)

Y_rec_df = hrec.reconcile(Y_hat_df=forecasts, Y_df=Y_train_df, S=S_df, tags=tags)

gives:
Exception: Check S_df, Y_hat_df series difference, S\Y_hat=425, Y_hat\S=1
Help, please?

What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

@James.. updated my query with the code that I tried using the heirarchicalforecasting library. Could you spot something?

Facing the same issue

Option A: The issue seems to come from your forecast not equaling the indices in your train-test-split. You can solve this by doing the following:
h=4
Y_test_df = Y_df.groupby('unique_id').tail(h)

Y_test_df = Y_test_df.reset_index(drop=True)
Y_train_df = Y_df[~Y_df.index.isin(Y_test_df.index)]

Just to check which indices are not lining up:
count_diff = len(S_df.index.difference(Y_hat_df.index))
print(len(S_df.index.unique()))
print(len(Y_hat_df.index.unique()))
print(count_diff)

Option B: This can also result when your hierarchical levels are not true top levels. This does not seem to be your case, but a brute force way of checking is to re-arrange the levels.
